# LUIS not recognizing word parts

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

I'm testing my LUIS app, I have an Intent called "Services" and other called "Insults" (for filtering insults, right). In "Services" Intent I have Utterances like "I want to see all the services" or "services" but when I test the word "servi" or "serv" it returns the "Insults" Intent instead of the "None" or "Services" Intent.

Let's say that LUIS is getting so strict and is only returning an Intent when I test an utterance that's EXACTLY the same I wrote at the Utterances of that Intent.

What can be causing this?

Comment: It depends on how you built your LUIS app, its content, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LUIS learns based on [active learning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/label-suggested-utterances). The algorithm should pick the unlabeled data that should be labelled depending on the confidence of the system in the prediction. In the active learning process, LUIS examines all the endpoint utterances, and selects utterances that it is unsure of. If you label these utterances, train, and publish, then LUIS identifies utterances more accurately. Have you trained any examples under None intent if not please do provide more training examples under "Insults" intent and "None" intent. Hope this helps.